# Delete hash item from within select

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to delete a hash item from within a select? I want to check if a file exists in a directory and if it does, remove it from the hash.

```
hash = {"http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/packages/ics/ics_4.0.0.tar.gz"=>"5103909285b549eda0b6a13dd503790a", ...}

hash.select do |k,v|
  if File.file?("#{k[/[^\/]+$/]}")
    # Remove from hash

  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot delete element in select, `delete_if` is a good choice.

```
hash.delete_if { |k,_| File.file?("#{k[/[^\/]+$/]}") }
```

update:

```
hash_copy = hash.dup

hash.select do |k,v|
  if File.file?("#{k[/[^\/]+$/]}")
    hash_copy.delete(k)
    ......
  end
end
```

Comment: I need to do a few more checks if the file matches so I don't think I can use a modifier like here.

Comment: You can make a copy of hash.

Comment: In "update", I don't understand why you are making a copy. If you just `select` or `reject` if will return the desired array and not mutate `hash`.

Comment: Because @Dru want to delete a hash item within a select，but cannot do that.

Comment: I don't understand. If you want to delete hash elements, use `delete_if`, as you have done (`delete_if` is the same as `Hash#reject!`, or use `Hash#select!`, which is the same as `Hash#keep_if`). If you want to return a hash without certain key-value pairs, and not change the original hash, use `Hash#select` or `Hash#reject`.

Comment: Thanks @pangpang. I had to do further checks so the dup method worked for me.

Comment: @CarySwoveland would you care to show an example of what you mean? Thanks.

Comment: Dru, suppose `h = {1=>'cat', 2=>'dog'}` and we wish to remove every key-value pair for which the key is odd. If we want to modify `h`, then  `h.reject! {|k,_| k.odd? }; h #=> {2=>'dog'}` (same as `delete_if`) or `h.select! {|k,_| k.even? }; h #=> {2=>"dog"}` (same as `keep_if`). If you don't want to mutate `h`, you could apply either of the above to `g=h.dup`, as pp suggested, but that's exactly the same as `g = h.reject {|k,_| k.odd? } #=> {2=>"dog"}` (or `select`--no `!`'s), which is more straightforward.